# Mood classification using libsvm

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, libsvm

I want to apply SVM on audio data det. I am extarcting difftrent features from the speech signal. After reducing the dimention of this matrix, I am still getting a features in matix form. Can anyone help me regarding the data formating
should i have to convert the feature matix in a row vector? Can i assign same label to each row of one feature matrix and other label to the rows of other matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Little bit ambiguous question but let me try to resolve your problem. For feature selection, you can use filter method, wrapper method etc. One popularly used method is principle component analysis. Once you select your feature you can directly feed them to the classifier. In your case, i guess you are getting lower dimensional representation of your training data (for example, if you have used SVD). In this case, its fine, now you can use it for SVM classification.

What did you mean by adding label to feature matrix? You can add label to the training instances, not the features. I guess you are talking about separate matrix for each of the class labels. If that is the case, yes you can use as you want but remember it depends on the model design.